# Querying array of nested objects

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I have this JSON (sample - a real-life example can be found at [apple itunes rss feed](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/genre=6000/json)) stored in a RethinkDB table called 'test':

```
{
    "feed": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "title": {
                    "label": "Some super duper app"
                },
                "summary": {
                    "label": "Bla bla bla..."
                }
            },
            {
                "title": {
                    "label": "Another awsome app"
                },
                "summary": {
                    "label": "Lorem ipsum blabla..."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How would I write a ReQL query in JavaScript in order to fetch the **summary** of all entries (`entry`) which have **title** containing the string "xyz"? I expect the query result to return an array of matching **entry** objects, not an array of matching **feed**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I properly understood what you want to do, this query should be what you are looking for:

```
r.table("feeds").concatMap(function(doc) {
    return doc("feed")("entry")
}).filter(function(entry) {
    return entry("title")("label").match("xyz")
})
```

Comment: @neumino, if there was "id" at the top level like:
{id:1, feed: ....} How to get this `id` after matching this text? for example: get all the ids of docs whose feed->entry->title->label match "xyz"? is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You can chain with `("id")` or `map(function(doc) { return doc("id") })`

Comment: @neumino could you elaborate a bit on that? where in the chain should I apply that `map` call? I've tried replicating it on a similar case but the stream resulting after `concatMap...filter` won't have the top level property (`id` in the example)

Comment: @neumino I found this gist of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976586/querying-array-of-nested-objects that solves my issue