# How to Peels off the elements of an array individually in rethinkdb?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I have documents like this:

```
{
   id:1,
  "A": [
    {
      "C": "abc",
      "D": [{X:"test"},{X:"test2"}]
    },
    {
      "C": "fg",
      "D":["X1"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get all id of document whose tag match A-> D -> X has value "test". I can use `concatMap()` but when I use it I am not able get "id" field and also cannot use it inside `map`, is there any similar features like `$unwind` of `Mongodb`'s aggregation framework?
Similar to :[Querying array of nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976586/querying-array-of-nested-objects)

[Original Question]

```
{
id:2,
tags[{a:3,b:4},..]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your originial question had this object:

```
{ id: 2,
  tags: [ { a: 3, b: 4 }, ... ] }
```

You can construct a predicate that finds the relevant documents, and pass it to `filter`.

```
r.table(...).filter(r.row('tags')('a').contains(3))('id')
```

In this case, the `('a')` part of the query, when applied to an array, returns an array of the `a` field of each object in that array, if there is one.

Your edited question has a more complicated object, but the principle is the same:

```
r.table(...).filter(
   r.row('A')('D').concatMap(function(x){return x})('X').contains("test")
)('id')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was expecting something different, so I edit my question. I have to go very deep inside object and array to check whether it exists or not and then finally I have to return first level element.